# How to set environment variables when using the VSCode Cloud Code extension?

Tags: google-cloud-code

I know how to set environment variables in Cloud Run using the web console (https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/environment-variables#setting), but how can I do this locally in the emulator when using VSCode with the Cloud Code extension?

I've only seen how to do it on the initial run (https://youtu.be/EtMIEtLQNa0?t=307) but not on subsequent runs. The advanced settings window no longer shows up when I rerun the command.
[image]

UPDATE:
There's also this explanation (of the same thing) here https://cloud.google.com/code/docs/vscode/develop-service, but I think this adds the settings to `launch.json`(?) which gets committed to git.

I tried adding a `.env` file but `process.env.MY_VARIABLE` is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, even when you use the advanced settings form on the initial run, it will save the environment variables to the `launch.json`. Pulling in variables from a specified file other than `launch.json` at runtime is not currently a supported feature in Cloud Code for VS Code.